# How can I get whole data in bigquery table, not data per day

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Hello I am new to bigquery.
I have linked to firebase data and get tables in bigquery. But the data show per day. May I know how can I get the whole data in bigquery table?

Answer (score 0):

That is a feature. Each day has it's own tables.

But you can write SQL query to read from all tables. See some examples here: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-analytics-bigquery

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query the whole dataset at once you can use wildcards by replacing the timestamps in the table by *

```
SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.app_events_*`
```